# Patch: AssertionError: Expected '...' to have been called once. Called 0 times

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest, python-mock

I have the following class to be tested.

**mod1/file1.py**

```
@dataclass
class Base(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    account: Account
    ec2_id: str = ""

    def start(self):
        self.account.session.resource("ec2").instances.filter(
            InstanceIds=[self.ec2_id]
        ).start()
```

And I created the following test,

```
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch

    @patch('mod1.file1.Base')
    def test_start(sut):
        sut.account = Mock()
        sut.ec2_id = 'test'
        sut.start()  # sut.return_value.start() gets the same error
        sut.account.session.resource('ec2').instances.filter.assert_called_once()
```

However, the test failed with error

```
AssertionError: Expected 'filter' to have been called once. Called 0 times.
```

Comment: You need `sut.return_value.start` as this is called by the instance. The question looks familiar, haven't you asked this before? And the same probably for the members, as this is a dataclass.

Comment: It got the same error after I changed to `sut.return_value.start.start()`.

Comment: Ah ok, my bad - this won't work because you mock `Base`, so the original `start` will not be called. You probably have to mock `Account` instead, though that depends on how `Account` is instantiated.

Comment: Actually you could just leave the code as is and instead of mocking `Base` just create a `Base` object as sut - that should work. Will put it in an answer for clarity...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the code is that you are mocking the object that you want to test. You have to mock any objects instantiated by your `sut` that you don't want to get created (because of unwanted side effect or complex initialization).
If an object is mocked, it cannot be tested, so calling patched object `sut` is most certainly wrong.

In your case you need to instantiate the real system under test, e.g. the dataclass, and only mock `Account` (as you do), so something like this should work:

```py
    def test_start():
        sut = Base()
        sut.account = Mock()
        sut.start()
        sut.account.session.resource('ec2').instances.filter.assert_called_once()
```

Note that setting `sut.ec2_id` has no impact, because `filter` is mocked and the arguments don't matter.

If this does really test the functionality you need to test is another matter.